How to do certain things in Staging Ground that we can do in the regular Stack Overflow
In Staging Ground, if I write a comment, and want to delete it later, I don't see a delete button such as there is on the regular site. How do I delete such a comment?
Also, how do I edit a Staging Ground question without leaving a comment? (Again this is something I can do on the regular site.)

Hum, "certain things" doesn't belong in a Title, like 'SG'-Users learn with a Canned Comment: Please [edit] the title of your question to be descriptive, unambiguous, and specific to what you are asking. For more guidance, see How do I write a good title?. // Not difficult to click once on the '3 dots' Button next to each Comment, I would think, ... to discover the 'Delete' option for your own Comments, ... and before you ask, the 'Flag' option for Comments that are from the Asker or other Reviewers.

would've been better to ask this as two separate question posts.


How do I delete such a comment?

You can delete your own comments using the three dots next to the comment.


Also, how do I edit a Staging Ground question without leaving a comment?

You can open the editing menu on a post using the "Edit" button below the post or using the "Edit post" review action.

After editing the post, you can select "Save without Review" in the menu on the right to edit it without a review (comment).


Again this is something I can do on the regular site.

Note that not all options from the main site are applicable to the Staging Ground. For instance, some closure reasons are removed because they are never applicable and "Requires Major Changes" should always be used instead (e.g. "Needs Details or Clarity") and downvoting is removed completely (as posts are not in a finished state).
